# Finding duplicate random numbers in an ArrayList

Tags: java, random, arraylist, duplicates

```
public class LotteryNumbers {
private ArrayList <Integer> numbers;

public LotteryNumbers() {
    this.numbers = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    this.drawNumbers();
}

public ArrayList <Integer> numbers() {
    return this.numbers;
}

public void drawNumbers() {
    Random random = new Random ();
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 7) {
        this.numbers.add(random.nextInt(39) + 1);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

This is a class used for printing 7 numbers from 1..39.

It does that job but the problem is I want the 7 random numbers to be different.

How do I check if an arrayList contains the same number since it is random?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: have you tried contains() ?? .. Or have you tried using a set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `contains()` method from the `ArrayList numbers`:

```
public void drawNumbers()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int counter = 0;
    int choice;
    while (counter < 7) {
        choice = random.nextInt(39) + 1;
        if (numbers.contains(choice)) {
            continue;
        }
        numbers.add(choice);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> **public boolean contains(Object o):** Returns true if this list contains
>   the specified element.

So, if the `ArrayList` already contains the `choice` (randomly generated), it will continue to the next iteration (`counter` won't be increased) and choose another random number. If it doesn't contains the `choice`, it will add it to the array and increase `counter`.

---

This can also be done by this way (without using `continue`)

```
if (!numbers.contains(choice)) {
    numbers.add(choice);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian!

This has worked.

I tried something like this and I now know why it did not work.

My mistake was that I put 

int choice = random.nextInt(39) + 1; outside of the loop, which kept giving me the same random number, but after reading your code I can now understand that I had to do it in the loop so I get a new random number every time.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> **How do I check if an ArrayList contains the same number since it is random?**

Like this (example):

```
public void drawNumbers() {
    Random random = new Random ();
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 7) {
        int newNumber = random.nextInt(39) + 1;
        if (! numbers.contains(newNumber)) {
            this.numbers.add(newNumber);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use contains as as the earlier responses suggest, however contains on an array list in inefficient with `O(n)` complexity. One of the comments by @TheLostMind suggest using a Set, the best Set implementation to use in this instance is `BitSet`, note it does not confirm to the `java.util.Set` interface specification.

```
public class LotteryNumbers {
private final int[] numbers = new int[7]

public LotteryNumbers() {
    this.drawNumbers();
}

public int[] numbers() {
    return this.numbers;
}

public void drawNumbers() {
    BitSet selected = new BitSet(40);
    Random random = new Random ();
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 7) {
        int num = random.nextInt(39) + 1;
        if(!selected.get(num)) {
          selected.flip(num);
          numbers[counter++] = num;
        }
    }

}
```

This implementation, tho unlikely, does not guarantee that you will always get a result.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put your numbers in a list and use COllections.shuffle and get the first 7 occurences.

You do not need to check if duplicate...

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    ....

Collections.shuffle(list);

loop and get your numbers...

int num = Integer.intValue(list.get(i));