# Android, randomize arrayList.add(Object)

Tags: java, random, arraylist

How to randomize ArrayList.add(Object)?

```
Random random = new Random();

ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add((Object)("one"));
arrayList.add((Object)("two"));
arrayList.add((Object)("three"));
arrayList.add((Object)("four"));
arrayList.add((Object)("five"));
```

Comment: what does `randomize ArrayList.add` mean?

Comment: How can i randomize above code? not sure how else could i explain?

Comment: @njzk2, I believe Mihir wants to insert new items at a random position in the ArrayList.

Comment: [Randomise after adding the values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist)

Comment: Thanks PrR3 - i was looking for "Collections.shuffle(arrayList);

Comment: yes, my crystal ball even works... ;)

Comment: Guys i'm getting -5 points for this question, how else one could ask this question?

Comment: Most of the downvotes are likely because this question is easily solvable with a little bit of research, and a good StackOverflow question demonstrates shows that you have made an attempt to research your question before asking.

Comment: i did know how to randomize regular array, but didn't know how to randomize above array. Oh well, next time will be more careful :) thanks

Comment: downvotes come from this question being solvable by googling `random arraylist` and a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method of accomplishing this is to call [`Collections.shuffle(List, Random)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) on your ArrayList after you have inserted all of the elements.

If you really want to do this as you insert the items instead, you can use [`add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to specify the position at which you need to insert the item. Something like this would do:

```
arrayList.add(random.nextInt(arrayList.size()), "MyString");
```