# How To Shuffle String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, shuffle

How Can I Shuffle below array

```
String[] firstName =["a","b","c","d","e"];
String[] lastName =["p","q","r","s","t"];
String[] salary =["10","20","30","40",50"];
String[] phoneNo= ["1","2","3","4","5"];
```

after shuffling the array i need result like

```
String[] firstName =["d","b","e","c","a"];
String[] lastName =["s","q","t","r","p"];
String[] salary =["40","20","50","30",10"];
String[] phoneNo= ["4","2","5","3","1"];
```

means for example if index of `"a"` from `firstName` Changes from 0 to  4, respective index of   `"p"`,`"10"`,`"1"` to be changed from 0 to 4..

Comment: @Sabik JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Did you begin with something or are you hoping someone will dump you the code?

Comment: One of the best ways to accomplish this would be to create a custom object with those 4 String fields. Then you can have a constructor such as `MyObject(String fN, String lN, String sal, String pN)` and use that to set initial values. Then create an array of `MyObject`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist

Answer (score 10):

If you task isn’t implementation of the snuffle algorithm you can use standard [java.util.Collections#shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) method:

```
String[] firstName = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(firstName);
Collections.shuffle(strList);
firstName = strList.toArray(new String[strList.size()]);
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i have got solution for it

Answer (score 2):

just create an array (or list) which has the values

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[firstName.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}

Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

and then just create a new string array to move the values into

```
string[] newFirstName = new string[arr.length]();
for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    newFirstName[i] = firstName[arr[i]];
    //etc ....
}
```

Comment: What if my Array is of X length....??

Comment: well all of the examples you used above were using the same sorting order. so i assumed you had a set order and length. does the shuffle need to be random?

Comment: thats what i need for arrays of Unknown some X length

Comment: if you need to randomize the list then see the comments above from others