# How to add buttons in arraylist and shuffle

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I have 4 number buttons in my application. I want to put the buttons in array list and shuffle them. How would I do this?

The buttons are used for generating random 4 digit pin.

Comment: Where's exactly the problem? With putting buttons into an ArrayList or with shuffling the list?

Comment: There is no problem.  I want to know How would I do it?

I want to put buttons in array list first and then shuffle them

Comment: But you want to do what? Read carefully what I wrote.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist) to shuffle the contents of arraylist

Comment: @slanecek  I want to put buttons into arraylist

Comment: You should be able to figure this out by looking at the documentation for java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Collections.