# How can I get a random number between two ranges?

Tags: java, random

I need to show the numbers 1-10 in a random order. An example outpue while executing first time would be: `5,4,8,7,9,1,2,3`. An example while executing second time would be: `7,6,5,1,2,3,4,9,8`

Will the following code print all date between ranges in random?

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
```

Comment: Where does dates come in?

Comment: Do you mean _data_, instead of _date_?

Comment: The following code does nothing but generate a random number

Comment: Why is there no 6 and 10 in the first example, and no 10 in the second? Do you want to actually do a [random shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1519736/1270789)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method. (more info on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229001/2271834))

In your example:

```
List<int> numbers = new ArrayList<int>();
int min = 65;
int max = 85;
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Comment: i have found the solution myself dude .. by the same shuffel meathod... i tried in random but... dulication of numbers occurs there... soo this is simple and better... thxxxx u @FlyingPumba

Comment: I'm glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Using shuffle works too. This is how you would manually do it.

```
Random r = new Random();

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=min ;  i<= max ; i++){

list.add(i); // adding your data

}

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>().addAll(list); 
//you don't need to use 
//list2 if you are ok with losing list. 
//As here list2 is being emptied ..

while(list2.size() > 0){

 int randomIndex = r.nextInt(0, list2.size);
 System.out.println(list.get(randomIndex));

 list2.remove(randomIndex);
 }
```

Comment: i have found the solution myself dude .. by the same shuffel meathod... i tried in random but... dulication of numbers occurs there... soo this is simple and better... thxxxx u @Yosif Mansour...