# Best practise for random generator Java

Tags: java, arraylist, random

Having an array of numbers I want to randomly pick every index of it with a random generator. What is the best practise for the random generator to avoid useless loops on indexes that have already selected? So far I use an ArrayList tho store the already selected ones but I feel that in the end this algorithm will have many wasted loops in the end. Here is the code:

```
Random r = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> found = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(notAllPassed){
   int prediction = r.nextInt(sizeOfArray);
   if(!found.contains(prediction){
      found.Add(prediction);
      //Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. build a list of indices. 2. shuffle the list.

Comment: To expand a little on what @MarkoTopolnik said (in case it is not obvious). Search for shuffling algorithm.

Comment: @markbernard No need. `Collections.shuffle()`

Comment: You can also use HashSet to store the random number instead of first storing it in ArrayList

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik LOL, been in the Collections class so many times and never noticed that.

Comment: Yes the shuffle idea is very good thanks.put it as an aswer so I can vote it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-arraylist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is, instead of choosing a random index each time, to prepare a shuffled list of all indices and just iterate over it in order.

```
List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, sizeOfArray).boxed().collect(toList());
Collections.shuffle(indices);
for (int randomIndex : indices) {
   // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking if you have things already generated, approach it differently. Create an array of all possible values and then shuffle the array randomly.

You can utilize built-in method `java.util.Collection.shuffle(List)`

For the initial list, order doesn't matter, but it is easiest to just fill it with 0..n-1 or 1..n values one after another. Doing it in more complex way is not helping in any way, as shuffle is anyway fully random.

Answer (score 0):

*Marko Topolnik* is absolutly right with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40507493/896249). Thats the best way to do it.

So my answer is just for the sake of completion, following your initial idea with `Random`

```
    Random r = new Random();                      // as you had it
    ArrayList<Integer> found = new ArrayList<>(); // as you had it

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){         // if you want ALL possible indexes 
        int prediction = r.nextInt(sizeOfArray);  // exactly as you did it
        while(found.contains(prediction)){        // here we check if the "found" list already contains the random index
            prediction = r.nextInt(sizeOfArray);  // if so, regenerate the "prediction" until one is generated that is not in the list
        }
        found.add(prediction);                    // this statement will only be reached after the while loop found an index that is not in the list
    }

    System.out.println(found.toString());         // convenience: print the list to see for yourself
```

As I said, this is just following your initial idea to use random. I would have done it this way, if there was no `Collection.shuffle()` :)