# Trying to find the pattern for flipping numbers

Tags: java, methods, stdin

If a user inputs some numbers like this (number of lines are arbitrary):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need to create a method that makes a series of outputs like this:

First output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Second output:

```
2
1
3
4
5
```

Third output:

```
4
3
2
1
5
```

Fourth output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

I'm just confused with the pattern that is being utilized here.

Comment: You missed one between the second and the third.

Comment: I copied this example from the instructions I was given. That is actually the only place I'm confused with.

Comment: We are also confused. What is your question exactly? And how is it on-topic for a site about programming (as opposed to puzzling) ?

Comment: With the given input,  I need to "flip" the input by following some sort of pattern. I'm just trying to figure out how to proceed. If you want to explain with code, by all means.

Comment: Is the pattern fixed or do you want a random pattern? For random, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228975/how-to-randomize-two-arraylists-in-the-same-fashion (do it like the code in the question)

Comment: It has to be fixed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must flip from the middle on each iteration i the sub sequence from 0 to i*2 -1.
Pseudo code assuming that seq is the input sequence:

```
void pattern(seq){
  print(seq)//First output
  for(int i=1;i*2<=seq.length-1;i++){
    seq = concatenate(seq.subSquence(i,i*2-1), seq.subSquence(0,i-1), seq.subSquence(i*2,seq.length-1) );
    print(seq)
  }
  seq = concatenate(seq.subSquence(i,seq.length-1), seq.subSquence(0,i-1))
  print(seq)//Last output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to take always `next_element` from original structure (array, list) and place it top.(others elements goes down by 1 till `next element` initial position)
`next_element` is start from second_position and it's increment by 1 till the end of structure (length or size)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    new Test().compute(a1);

    int a2[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    new Test().compute(a2);


}

public void compute(int[] a)
{
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        //i : next_element which will be place always on first_position
        int temp= a[i];

        //j : current_element (iterate by till next_element)
        for(int j=i; j>0; j--)
        {
                a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[0] = temp;
        String str = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().map(t->String.valueOf(t)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println("step="+i+": array="+str);
    }
}

}
```

Output

```
step=1: array=2,1,3,4,5
step=2: array=3,2,1,4,5
step=3: array=4,3,2,1,5
step=4: array=5,4,3,2,1
```

and (reverse)

```
step=1: array=4,5,3,2,1
step=2: array=3,4,5,2,1
step=3: array=2,3,4,5,1
step=4: array=1,2,3,4,5
```